# Is it possible to set local variable to allow any value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a series of queries that are used for QA. Normally we are limiting the `organizationid` to a single value but occasionally we want to return all `organizationid`'s. Is it possible to do this without having to comment out all of the `@orgid`'s within the query?

Example:

```
DECLARE @REPSD DATETIME = '10-01-2014';
DECLARE @REPED DATETIME = '09-30-2015';
DECLARE @orgid BIGINT = 5

SELECT
    patientid,
    MAX (dateofobservation) sbp_date INTO #t1
FROM
    dbo.patientobservation (nolock)
WHERE observationcode IN ('8479-8','8480-6','8459-0','8460-8','8461-6')
    AND dateofobservation >= @REPSD
    AND dateofobservation <= @REPED 
    AND organizationid = @orgid
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using NOLOCK unless you really understand that hint. And if you are going to use it you should use proper syntax. Omitting the WITH keyword for index hints is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Here is a great article discussing the evils of that hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want:

```
DECLARE @REPSD DATETIME = '10-01-2014';
DECLARE @REPED DATETIME = '09-30-2015';
DECLARE @orgid BIGINT = NULL

SELECT
    patientid,
    MAX (dateofobservation) sbp_date INTO #t1
FROM
    dbo.patientobservation (nolock)
WHERE observationcode IN ('8479-8','8480-6','8459-0','8460-8','8461-6')
    AND dateofobservation >= @REPSD
    AND dateofobservation <= @REPED 
    AND organizationid = ISNULL(@orgid,organizationid);
```

or:

```
SELECT
    patientid,
    MAX (dateofobservation) sbp_date INTO #t1
FROM
    dbo.patientobservation (nolock)
WHERE observationcode IN ('8479-8','8480-6','8459-0','8460-8','8461-6')
    AND dateofobservation >= @REPSD
    AND dateofobservation <= @REPED 
    AND 
    (
        (organizationid = @orgid AND @orgid IS NOT NULL)
        OR @orgid IS NULL
    )
```

Using `JamieD77` suggestion which is equivalent of above but simpler and more compact:

```
AND (@orgid IS NULL OR organizationid = @orgid)
```

You should consider using third example, because the first is not-SARGable so query optimizer won't use indexes on that column if exists any.

Comment: the isnull isnt bad, but wouldnt you use `(@orgid is null OR organizationid = @orgid)` for the second?

Comment: @JamieD77 That looks simpler and neat. Thanks

Comment: @lad2025 - went with the first solution and it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: In the second option there is not need to have @orgid IS NOT NULL. It is redundant. If the value in the table is NULL it would not be returned because of the way NULLs work with equality.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I know. But I will leave it as is. I've already added JamieD77 suggestion

Comment: I would recommend the second option since the first one is nonSARGable which means it can't us an index on the organizationid column. The second option is SARGable and will perform better on larger tables.